# How come I cannot use bp_core_fetch_avatar() in the theme after I add filter in the plugin, wordpress buddypress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

After I do the add_filter code below in the first plugin, I cannot use bp_core_fetch_avatar() in the second plugin or in the theme, it echo out the same avatar for every user, why? How can I fix this? get_avatar can echo out different avatar base on the user except that it cannot recognize the $gender that I create in the plugin which will tell if it is a female or male, so avatar will assign base on gender . I am trying to pass some parameter like $gender that I created in the plugin, so that is why I think I should figure out to use bp_core_fetch_avatar(), by the way, does get_avatar can pass a parameter from a plugin?, I know get_avatar( $id, $size,$default, $alt). Anyway, I want to know why bp_core_fetch_avatar() echo out same avatar for every user after do the add_filter, I already add 'item_id'=>"$id". Thanks

```html
           <?php
          add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar',array($this,'set_buddypress_avatar'), 10, 1);

       ?>
```

```html
<?php
public function set_buddypress_avatar($html_data = ''){

  $html_doc = new DOMDocument();
  $html_doc->loadHTML($html_data);
  $image = $html_doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  foreach($image as $data) {
   $original_image = $data->getAttribute('src');
   $size = $data->getAttribute('width');
   $alt = $data->getAttribute('alt');
      
   if (stripos($alt, 'Profile picture of ') === 0){ // if our alt attribute has "profile picture of" in the beginning...
    $name = str_replace('Profile picture of ', '', $alt);
      
   } else if (stripos($alt, 'Profile photo of ') === 0){ // or profile photo of...
    $name = str_replace('Profile photo of ', '', $alt);
       
   } else { // if there is some problem - just assign alt to name
    $name = $alt;
       
   }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why bp_core_fetch_avatar() echo out same avatar for
>   every user after do the add_filter

Because you **added a filter** to a core BP function. 
Try removing the filter after you are finished with it in your class.

[remove_filter#Example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter#Example)

Comment: are you suggesting me that I should remove the filters. I confuse now, if I remove the filters, then I will lose those function that I add_filter,right? But, I still need the add_filter function. thanks for your time, I will try remove_filter later, and see can I can the avatar and still have the add_filters functoin